# Display click count and redirect to a url

Tags: javascript, html, click, counter, redirect

I have found the below code to check the count of times the button has been clicked. However, I would like the button to redirect to an URL once it is clicked and update the click count.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Increment count when button is clicked</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <input type="button" value="Count" id="countButton" />

    <p>The button was pressed <span id="displayCount">0</span> times.</p>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var count = 0;
      var button = document.getElementById("countButton");
      var display = document.getElementById("displayCount");

      button.onclick = function(){
        count++;
        display.innerHTML = count;
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want to save your count in the database and then redirect to other page?

Comment: I want to store it in the cookie or local storage.

Answer (score 0):

```
button.onclick = function(){
  count++;
  display.innerHTML = count;
  window.location = "http://jonathanmh.com";
}
```

This would do the trick, but nobody would ever see the number, because it simply goes away, after the user is redirected to another page. If you want to save the number for other users to see, you need to save it on the server and preferably in a database.

Comment: you can store that number in cookie or localStorage - no need for db.

Comment: How do I store the number in the cookie?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that you need to store click count in cookie or localStorage (or anywhere else where your data persists):

```
var button = document.getElementById("countButton");
var display = document.getElementById("displayCount");

button.onclick = function(){
    if (isNaN(localStorage.yourCounter))
        localStorage.yourCounter = 0;
    localStorage.yourCounter++;
    display.innerHTML = localStorage.yourCounter;
    window.location = 'http://jsfiddle.net/'
}
```

Comment: For some reason I cannot save jsfiddle with that code - it redirects me to http://jsfiddle.net/ when I save or update